# Finding $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(x_n)}{n}$ for a given sequence $(x_n)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Given a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_0=1$ and $x_n=\begin{cases}2x_{n-1}+1, & n&\text{is odd}\\
> 3x_{n-1}+2, & n & \text{is even} \end{cases}$

How do I show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(x_n)}{n} = \frac{1}{2}\log6$?

Comment: Hint: Consider how the $x_i$ values relate from an odd value of $i$ to the next odd value, i.e., $i + 2$, as well as among each increasing even index.

Comment: @JohnOmielan the coefficient of $x_0$ is increasing by multiples of $6$ but I don't know how to proceed using this fact.

Comment: Here's another hint. Considering just the odd indices, e.g., define a sub-sequence $y_i = x_{2i-1}$,you have a [Linear difference equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation) among the $y_i$ which  you can actually fairly easily solve explicitly. You can do the same for the even indices as well. There are, however, somewhat easier ways to solve this, but they are somewhat harder to describe as hints instead of as answers.

Comment: I found the following relation: $x_{2n+3}-x_{2n+1} = 10\cdot 6^n(x_0+1)$ for $n=0,1,2,\dots$, then what?